# AWK Hangs While Chunking

Tags: awk

the following Awk code chunks out the file grep-diff.log between the two patterns /^[+]{3}/ and /^$/. Remove newlines in between with space.

This works but recently it has started to hang and I'm unable to debug it.

Any tips or tricks on how to do this more efficently would be welcomed.

```
awk -v g=0 '{if ($0 ~ /^[+]{3}/) {chunk=$0 }
else if ($0 ~ /^$/) {chunkAry[g]=chunk; chunk=""; g+=1}
else {chunk=chunk " " $0}}
END {chunkAry[g]=chunk; chunk="";
for (c in chunkAry) print "Chunk : ",c, " " chunkAry[c]}' $(pwd)/grep-diff.log > "$(pwd)/chunked-diff.log"
```

## Reply to comments 1

Thanks for the heads up Ed, much apprecicated.

I've taken your advice and got rid of the array, and added the debug line, but the script still hangs with no error.

Here is the revised code -

```
awk -v g=0 '{if ($0 ~ /^[+]{3}/) {chunk=$0 }
else if ($0 ~ /^$/) {print "Chunk ",g," : ",chunk; chunk=""; g+=1}
else {chunk=chunk " " $0}}
END {print "Chunk ",g," : ",chunk; chunk=""; print "Here : " | "cat>&2"}' $(pwd)/grep-diff.log > "$(pwd)/chunked-diff.log"
```

The "this" is to take all lines between regex /^[+]{3}/ and /^$/ inclusive of patterns and remove all newlines occurrence and save to output file.

The input file grep-diff.log is 90 MB. Awk hangs on the 256th occurrence out of a total of 276. The chunk of text it hangs on is 80 KB, but there are no anomalies other than it's size is by far the largest chunk in the file. The full 80 KB chunk has 1727 file lines, Awk hangs on line 1718, where there is nothing strange.

Does Awk have a buffer size limit that can be set? Something similar happened last week with Node JS, where a manual buffer limit size increase fixed the issue.

## Update

I cut out the chunk that was causing the script to hang, and guess what, the script still hangs on the 256th occurrence. The new 256th chunk is tiny, so it's not the chunk size.Hmmm what could it be?

Comment: Did it occur to you to add a `print "here" | "cat>&2"` at the start of the END section to see if it's being reached? The only way that script can hang is if it's input file hangs, i.e. remains open with nothing else being written to it. So look into whatever is creating grep-diff.log, add that debugging print statement to confirm that the END is never reached and next time this script hangs kill the process that's writing to grep-diff.log to see this script complete and then start debugging that other script.

Comment: and wrt `how to do this more efficiently` it all depends what `this` is (e.g. right now there doesn't seem to be any reason for you to be using an array at all but sample input/output would clear that up)  - add concise, testable sample input and expected output for help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention that I was running this script on Mac OX 10.12.6, so the awk tool in use is not GNU's. Subsequently I installed GNU Gawk using brew (brew install gawk) and ran the same code, but changing the keyword awk for gawk. Now the script executes without error.